# Recursive string substitution

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
x = "{app}_{filename}"

def fun():
    app = 'java'
    filename = 'gc.log'
    result = f'{x}'
    print(result) 
fun()
```

This will print "{app}_{filename}" but my goal is to substitute {app} and {filename} with local ones. I have googled on how to do recursive variable substitution but didn't find anything.

Comment: Do you need to solve this specifically by using recursive substitution, or do you just want the desired result easily?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I just want the desired result.

Comment: This is easier *without* f-strings, just do `x.format(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to substitute the variables in your string template with something like:

```
x = "{app}_{filename}"

def fun(s):
    app = 'java'
    filename = 'gc.log'
    return s.format(app=app, filename=filename)

print(fun(x))
# prints: "java_gc.log"
```